# Get Client Computer and user name in local intranet site

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic

We have been running an ASP application in local intranet using IIS7 and now have requirement to get Client computer name and logged user name, so that we can show his home page according to his setting. I did search on internet but did not find any solution yet. I also tried using LOGON_USER server variables but it works fine when I run using localhost but not when use IP Address (Return blank value). I also enabled window authentication and disabled anonymous but I prompt for user name and password even I did not set user name and password.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to determine the computername directly.  You will need to perform a reverse DNS lookup on the client's IP.  Check out the link below from ASP101 to accomplishing this in ASP classic.

As far as the username, you will need to enable authentication in IIS otherwise all incoming requests will be anonymous.  If you are running in a trusted environment, setup IIS for "Integrated Windows Authentication".  This will allow the client's current user information to be used to authenticate to your website without a userid/password prompt.  Note that integrated authentication is not part of the default IIS7 install.

Good luck.

ASP based Reverse DNS Lookup
http://www.asp101.com/articles/jason/reversedns/default.asp

Integrated Windows Authentication in IIS6 and IIS7
http://blogs.iis.net/nitashav/archive/2010/03/12/iis6-0-ui-vs-iis7-x-ui-series-integrated-windows-authentication.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this by using WMI, however the remote computer and logged on user must be part of a domain that you have the administration credentials for. You will also need to use reverse DNS to find out the computer name, which @jking89 has given a great reference to above. Take a look at the WMI Win32_ComputerSystem class, here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394102(VS.85).aspx. Hope this helps as an alternate solution.

Comment: Here is another reference for using the WMI Win32_ComputerSystem class remotely http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384713(VS.85).aspx. I couldn't post more than one hyperlink as i haven't gained enough reputation points yet =)